# Cannot deploy application with SQL Server CE database.file

Tags: c#, database, file, sql-server-ce

I am trying to deploy a simple windows desktop app using a SQL Server `database.sdf` file. I have followed the steps in this walkthrough about 10 times and I still am having problems. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546200.aspx

In my `app.config` file my connection string is this:

```
<add name="VendorTracker_2._0.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString"
     connectionString="Data Source=C:\Users\Eamon\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\VendorTracker 2.0\VendorTracker 2.0\Database1.sdf"
     providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5" />
```

According to the walkthrough, the windows installer should recognize that I am using a SQL Server CE `.sdf` file and create a new connection string:

```
<add name="VendorTracker_2._0.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString1"
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf"
     providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5" />
```

It does add this connection string to the `app.config` file. Now I have both connection strings listed in the `app.config` file. When I deploy the app onto my development computer, it works fine, no problem connecting to the `.sdf` file.

But when I copy the install folder and everything inside of it to a different "testing" computer I get the following error when I try to run the app:

> The path is not valid. Check the directory for the database. [ Path=C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\VendorTracker 2.0 Database1.sdf].

The app continues to run but there is no data and It will not allow me to save anything to the database.

Why doesn't the `.sdf` file get deployed with the connection string:

```
Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf
```

like it is suppose to? Driving me nuts. I have tried everything. Has anyone successfully used a SQL Server CE `.sdf` file with a stand alone windows desktop app? I know they are used a lot for mobile devices but that shouldn't make a difference. Please help.

Oceantrain

Comment: Did you try removing the non-relative path string?

Comment: Yes I removed the non relative path string and just left the |Data Directory| string. Still no luck.

Comment: What's the problem if you only have the `|Data Directory|` path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the connection string manually. Also, consider carefully where you place the file, as not all places are writable

Comment: Why doesn't click once deployment "place" the file in the appropriate place to begin with? I don't understand why it's so difficult to deploy a simple windows app with an .sdf file and install it on a test computer.